# Google App Script - How to join multiple databases in JDBC query

Tags: mysql, google-apps-script, jdbc

Is it possible to join multiple databases through a GAS query? I am successfully able to join data across tables but cannot figure out how to join databases.

Here is my script for joining tables. What do I need to add/change to join this query to another database table (databases are on the the same server).

````
  var docs = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = docs.getSheetByName('sheet1');
  var protocol = docs.getSheetName();
  var siteName = docs.getName();
  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection('jdbc:mysql://ip:port/database', 'foo', 'bar'); 

var stmt = conn.prepareStatement("select a.ex, a.ex2, a.ex3, b.ex1, b.ex2 from table1 a join table2 b on a.ex = b.ex;"); 

  var start = new Date(); // Get script starting time
  var rs = stmt.executeQuery();
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var sheets = docs.getSheetByName('sheet1');
  var cell = sheets.getRange('C1');
  var row = 0;
  var getCount = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); 

  for (var i = 0; i < getCount; i++){  
     cell.offset(row, i).setValue(rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i+1)); 
  }  

  var row = 1; 
  while (rs.next()) {
    for (var col = 0; col < rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); col++) { 
      cell.offset(row, col).setValue(rs.getString(col + 1)); 
    }
    row++;
  }

  rs.close();
  stmt.close();
  conn.close();
  var end = new Date(); // Get script ending time
  Logger.log('Time elapsed: ' + (end.getTime() - start.getTime())); // To generate script log. To view log click on View -> Logs.
  Logger.log(protocol);
  Logger.log(rs);

}```
````

Comment: I'd guess try declaring two separate connections conn1 and conn2

Comment: @Cooper Tried that - the issue with that became declaring both connections in the "var stmt = conn.prepareStatement()" area. Not sure how I would go about connecting both variables to that statement...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to create a **stored procedure** in MySQL. You can link the databases there, creating complex queries, and then call the procedure in the JDBC query using a single connection to the database which holds the stored procedure.

This worked for me.

Links to relevant materials:

Dev MySQL Site: [MySQL Stored Procedure](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-stored-procedures.html)

MySQL Tutorial: [MySQL Stored Procedure](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-stored-procedure/)